# SQLAlchemy 'This transaction is closed' error after some insertions

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, exception, sqlalchemy

I am using `Flask` with `SQLAlchemy` (both on their own, so without `Flask-SQLAlchemy`) to build a REST API against a PostgreSQL instance.

To test the API manually, I send several requests with random data to the API by performing a POST request using the `requests` module. As the later API is not heavily bombarded with data (one request each 10 seconds), I decided to send a request every 2 seconds for testing purposes.

In general, this approach works as expected. I was able to initialize the empty database with the required tables and write data to each table via my API. However, after some arbitrary number of requests, an `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed` exception is raised (see full traceback below).

The session is bound to Flask's `app` instance inside my `routes.py` like this:

```
# -- app/routes.py --
# (simplified version)

from http import HTTPStatus

from flask import request, jsonify

from app import app
from . import db


app.session = db.connector.Session()


@app.route('/')
def root_endpoint():
    return 'This is the root endpoint.'


@app.route('/api/v1.0/measurement/', methods=['POST'])
def post_measurement():
    measurements = request.json
    # doing some data parsing here ...
    measurements = [db.models.Measurement(**measurement) for measurement in measurements]

    app.session.add_all(measurements)
    app.session.commit()

    ids = [m.id for m in measurements]

    return jsonify({"message": "Created new measurements.", "ids": ids}), HTTPStatus.CREATED
```

The database session (scoped session) is provided by `connector.py` from my `db` module:

```
# -- db/connector.py --
# (simplified version)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

DB_SERVER_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/grafana"

engine = create_engine(
    DB_SERVER_URL,
    echo=True,
)

session_factory  = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
    autoflush=False,
    autocommit=False,
)

Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

Base = declarative_base()
```

In addition, the database model `Measurement` is defined as so (`db/models.py`):

```
# -- db/connector.py --
# (simplified version))

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime, Float, Integer, String

from .connector import Base


class Measurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'measurement'

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    timestamp = Column(
        DateTime,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )

    payload = Column(
        Float,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )

    payload_type = Column(
        String,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
```

As already stated, I get an exception with the following traceback after an arbitrary number of requests. All other POST request thereafter will also fail (due to this unresolved error).

I think, this must be related to session and transaction management, but I do not get what I am missing here. How can I narrow this issue down? What am I missing here?

---

Traceback of first exception (resulting in HTTP status code 500):

```
[2021-01-09 19:25:19,930] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1.0/measurement/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2642, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 621, in execute
    persistence.delete_obj(
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 325, in delete_obj
    states_to_delete = list(
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 462, in _organize_states_for_delete
    for state, dict_, mapper, connection in _connections_for_states(
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1602, in _connections_for_states
    connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 312, in connection
    self._assert_active()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 305, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/app/routes.py", line 137, in post_measurement
    app.session.commit()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1046, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2540, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2682, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 82, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(value, with_traceback=traceback)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2682, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 520, in rollback
    self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True, rollback_ok=True)
  File "/home/co16/flaskapi/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 305, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
```

Comment: You should be creating (and removing) a session for each request.  See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions

Comment: Addition to @snakecharmerb's comment: There is a short introduction about using SQLAlchemy with Flask [in the Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/). The comment and the overview in the docs helped to solve my problem.